# LUIS API - Retrieve all endpoint utterances and its scores

Tags: azure, api, artificial-intelligence, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I have been searching the past few days how to retrieve the endpoint utterances and its scores for a dashboard I am working with. Problem is I'm lost with the APIs, there seems to be many, but I cannot find the exact one that fits my need.

In this API documentation [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/58aeface39e2bb03dcd5909e), there is one that gets example utterances. What I would want to get is the actual endpoint utterances.

Anyone can point me where to find the API to use? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean to pass `UserUtterance` to LUIS and check the `Intent` and `Score` of that from LUIS endpoint?

Comment: Nope, what i meant was to get all list of user utterrances and its conficence scores

Comment: Did you try with the get review labeled examples (https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c0a)?

Comment: yes i did, its not what we were looking for. its based on sampling, not on the actual user utterances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this one working now, got it from this [forums](https://forums.asp.net/t/2142213.aspx?LUIS%20How%20to%20get%20utterances%20under%20Review%20Endpoint%20Utterances%20using%20LUIS%20API%20v2%200).

```
https://<REGION>.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0/apps/<APP_ID>/versions/0.1/intents/<INTENT_ID>/suggest?multiple-intents=true
```

Just confused a bit, I do not find the use of the INTENT_ID here. I'm not sure if this was intended or was a fault on the api design.

But anyways, did the job, got all the user utterances and its confidence scores.
Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

@Jeff, actually in that API docs that you linked, the answer was there, however perhaps not under the most obvious name.

You're looking for **Download application query logs**, which has this request URL

```
https://[location].api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0/apps/{appId}/querylogs/[?includeResponse]
```

[GET Download application query logs](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c36) - Gets the query logs of the past month for the application.

The response is 200 as a CSV file containing the query logs for the past month.

Comment: hi, yes i actually got to test that one, but wont be viable in my case, not unless there is no other way around (last resort)