# Get Sentences added on LUIS

Tags: javascript, azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I need to implement Autofill option to our bot solution.
For that, is there any option to retrieve all the sentences added in Luis in each intent?
Is there any API available?
I am exploring option to use LUIS as source for my autofill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57185229/5209435). The LUIS API is also available [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c40).

Comment: Thanks Matt. Let me check

Comment: Thanks Matt. I am able to get the Data :-)